How To Utilize Server Response Code From Another Domain With JavaScript
First of all, I want to point out that I'm aware of cross-domain issues with JavaScript.
I would not have considered this possible, except that I do see 404/200 response codes in my console.
The intention...
I'm working on a website prototype that is showing a video player, based on a number of possible file options.
I'm trying to create logic that says:
if this file is available, play it
if it's not available, try this other file
if that file is available, play it
if it's not available, try this other file
etc...
At first, I tried doing it with XMLHttpRequest().
The problem was that I couldn't figure out how to do if/else logic, since you have to specify the url in .open().
I found that jQuery's .ajax() function had an error/success option.
At that point, I thought that I might be able to nest .ajax() within error.
With that in mind, it is partially working.
I'm getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors, but I'm also getting legitimate 404/200 responses.
So, my question is "How can I incorporate those 404/200 responses into my code?"
JavaScript (and please let me know of a better way of doing this)...
function getSermonVideo() {
    "use strict";
    const params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
    const filename = params.get("filename");
    const site = params.get("site");
    let date = params.get("date");
    let shortdate = date.slice(2);
    shortdate = shortdate.replaceAll("-", "");
    const editedvideourl = "https://flcmedia.org/productvideo/";
    const editedaudiourl = "https://flcmedia.org/product/";
    let uneditedurl = "https://flcmedia.org/" + site + "/";
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:editedvideourl + filename + ".mp4",
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:editedvideourl + filename + "_480.mp4",
                type:'HEAD',
                error: function() {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url:editedaudiourl + filename + ".mp3",
                        type:'HEAD',
                        error: function() {
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                url: uneditedurl + "MP4/" + date.slice(0, 4) + "/" + shortdate + "Video.mp4",
                                type:'HEAD',
                                error: function() {
                                    jQuery.ajax({
                                        url: uneditedurl + "MP3/" + date.slice(0, 4) + "/" + shortdate + "Audio.mp3",
                                        type:'HEAD',
                                        error: function() {
                                            //console.log("No file exists.");
                                        },
                                        success: function() {
                                            videoplayer.src = uneditedurl + "MP3/" + date.slice(0, 4) + "/" + shortdate + "Audio.mp3"
                                        }
                                    });
                                },
                                success: function() {
                                    videoplayer.src = uneditedurl + "MP4/" + date.slice(0, 4) + "/" + shortdate + "Video.mp4"
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        success: function() {
                            videoplayer.src = editedaudiourl + filename + ".mp3";
                        }
                    });
                },
                success: function() {
                    videoplayer.src = editedvideourl + filename + "_480.mp4";
                }
            });
        },
        success: function() {
            videoplayer.src = editedvideourl + filename + ".mp4";
        }
    });
}

Edge Developer's Tools - Console...
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://flcmedia.org/productvideo/1214-GodsIncorruptibleWordSeed-01-HisWordIsMedicine.mp4' from origin 'https://anti-exe.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
    HEAD https://flcmedia.org/productvideo/1214-GodsIncorruptibleWordSeed-01-HisWordIsMedicine.mp4 net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://flcmedia.org/productvideo/1214-GodsIncorruptibleWordSeed-01-HisWordIsMedicine_480.mp4' from origin 'https://anti-exe.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
    HEAD https://flcmedia.org/productvideo/1214-GodsIncorruptibleWordSeed-01-HisWordIsMedicine_480.mp4 net::ERR_FAILED 404 (Not Found)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://flcmedia.org/product/1214-GodsIncorruptibleWordSeed-01-HisWordIsMedicine.mp3' from origin 'https://anti-exe.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
    HEAD https://flcmedia.org/product/1214-GodsIncorruptibleWordSeed-01-HisWordIsMedicine.mp3 net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://flcmedia.org/FLCSarasota/MP4/2017/171126Video.mp4' from origin 'https://anti-exe.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
    HEAD https://flcmedia.org/FLCSarasota/MP4/2017/171126Video.mp4 net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://flcmedia.org/FLCSarasota/MP3/2017/171126Audio.mp3' from origin 'https://anti-exe.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
    HEAD https://flcmedia.org/FLCSarasota/MP3/2017/171126Audio.mp3 net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)
Access to fetch at 'https://flcmedia.org/productvideo/1214-GodsIncorruptibleWordSeed-01-HisWordIsMedicine.mp4' from origin 'https://anti-exe.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
    GET https://flcmedia.org/productvideo/1214-GodsIncorruptibleWordSeed-01-HisWordIsMedicine.mp4 net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)

So, as you can see, I am getting some files coming back with 200 and others coming back with 404.
If I can use that information, then I can create my if/else logic to do what I'm attempting.
Do you have any ideas?

Can you change the headers on the other domain do allow your domain? If not you'll probably need a proxy.

"I'm getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors, but I'm also getting legitimate 404/200 responses." - but because of the CORS issue, you do not get access to those response status codes, in your JavaScript. You could try and simply assign the URL as source for a video element - and then add an error event handler to react, when the video can't be played. Although there might be other reasons it can't play, and the user experience probably won't be the best.

Other than that, you can only use a CORS proxy - at least for those HEAD requests, after you verified the URL "exists", you should be able to use it as a video source directly. (Unless the system where the video is hosted, explicitly checks for an Origin header.)

This didn't specifically address the 200/404 logic, but I was able to do what I was intending to (try this file, if it doesn't work try that file, if that doesn't work try the other file).
const videoplayer = document.getElementById("videoplayer");
function getSermonVideo() {
    "use strict";
    const params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
    const filename = params.get("filename");
    const site = params.get("site");
    const number = params.get("number");
    let date = params.get("date");
    let shortdate = date.slice(2);
    shortdate = shortdate.replaceAll("-", "");
    const editedvideourl = "https://flcmedia.org/productvideo/";
    const editedaudiourl = "https://flcmedia.org/product/";
    let uneditedurl = "https://flcmedia.org/" + site + "/";
    // default video file
    videoplayer.src = editedvideourl + filename + "_480.mp4";
    videoplayer.onerror = function () {
        console.log("Edited _480.mp4 not available.");
        videoplayer.src = editedvideourl + filename + ".mp4";
        videoplayer.onerror = function () {
            console.log("Edited .mp4 not available.");
            videoplayer.src = editedaudiourl + filename + ".mp3";
            videoplayer.onerror = function () {
                console.log("Edited .mp3 not available.");
                videoplayer.src = uneditedurl + "MP4/" + date.slice(0, 4) + "/" + shortdate + "Video.mp4";
                videoplayer.onerror = function () {
                    console.log("Unedited .mp4 not available.");
                    videoplayer.src = uneditedurl + "MP3/" + date.slice(0, 4) + "/" + shortdate + "Audio.mp3";
                    videoplayer.onerror = function () {
                        console.log("Unedited .mp3 not available.");
                    };
                };
            };
        };
    };
}

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but it does work.
It would probably work with more modern code (like CBroe mentioned)...
videoplayer.addEventListener("error", () => {
    videoplayer.src = editedaudiourl + filename + ".mp3";
});

But I wasn't sure how to nest them.  .onerror just made more sense, to me.
